# How do I stop null values from being assigned extreme color values?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster surface that I kriged in Surfer and imported to Grass GIS but when I view it in QGIS, the null values outside of the interpolated surface take an extreme value and wash out the resolution in the rest of my surface.  Is there an easy way to stop the null values from being assigned off the scale values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell QGIS to treat those NULL values as NULL values: Go to Transparency tab and set the value there. This value will then be ignored when calculating color maps.

An alternative is to set min/max values manually using "Custom min/max values" in Style tab.

Answer (score 0):

It works quite well to set the "No data value" in the upper right corner of the Transparency tab to 0.

Comment: Can you please expand a bit on this answer. It may be correct but to be helpful to future readers a bit of explanation/background often helps.

Comment: @Michael Stimson I am not sure why.  I assume the visual representation of "0" is nothing so there is nothing displayed in that part of the raster and therefore, the issue is resolved.